# Simple append list to class variable in python

Tags: python, class

I have this simple class in Python. Name is a string, events are list of strings.

```py
class Page(object):

    def __init__(self, name=None, events=None):
        self.name = name
        self.events = events or []

    def add(self, x):
        return self.events.append(x)

    @property
    def eventstring(self):
        return " , ".join(self.events)
```

I have this input:

```
 log = {'key1': [['e1', 'e2'], 'e3', ]], 'key2': ['e5', 'e6', 'e7']}
```

I want to create read in the log and produce list of pages. i.e.

```
[Page('key1', ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']), Page('key2', ['e5', 'e6', 'e7']}
```

My current code to create the list of Page objects doesn't work.  Plus, getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'` error msg.

```py
def inputevent(inputlog):
    final_pages = []
    pg = Page()
    for key, val in inputlog.items():
        pg.name = key
        for e in val:
            pg.events = pg.add(e)
        final_pages.append(pg)
    final_pages.append(pg)
return final_pages
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page.add()` returns `None`, but you are assigning it back to `pg.events`:

```
pg.events = pg.add(e)
```

This effectively clears `pg.events`. Since `pg.add()` alters `pg.events` in-place, there is no need to assign back to `pg.events` there at all:

```
for key, val in inputlog.items():
    pg.name = key
    for e in val:
        pg.add(e)
```